# Getting Amazon Cognito to work with angular2 and typescript

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito

Im trying to get Cognito’s Forgot password to work

Im using:
Angular2+Typescript+Ionic

I’m fairly new to this process, but I followed the Quickstart I found from here https://www.libhive.com/providers/npm/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js

No matter what I seem to do, I always get Cannot read property ‘CognitoUser’ of undefined, or an error similar to that

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';
import { ConfirmPage } from '../confirm/confirm';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import {Camera, CameraOptions} from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { Cognito } from '../../providers/aws.cognito';
import { User } from '../../providers/providers';
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/Media-Capture';
import {
    AuthenticationDetails,
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider,
    CognitoUser,
    CognitoUserAttribute,
    CognitoUserPool
} from "aws-cognito-identity";
declare var AWS: any;
declare const aws_cognito_identity_pool_id;
declare const aws_cognito_region;

var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
var CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;
var CognitoUser = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser;


recovery()
  {
    AWS.config.region = aws_cognito_region;
    var CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;
    var userData = {
        Username : ‘testuser’,
        Pool : aws_cognito_identity_pool_id
    };
    
    var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
    

        // call forgotPassword on cognitoUser
        cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
            onSuccess: function(result) {
                console.log('call result: ' + result);
            },
            onFailure: function(err) {
                alert(err);
            },
            inputVerificationCode() { // this is optional, and likely won't be implemented as in AWS's example (i.e, prompt to get info)
                var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code ', '');
                var newPassword = prompt('Enter new password ', '');
                cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
            }
        });
    
    alert("It should have worked");
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have sorted it out in following way by importing all what I required

```
    import {
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider,
    AuthenticationDetails,
    CognitoUserPool,
    CognitoUser,
    CognitoUserAttribute,
    ICognitoUserAttributeData,
    ISignUpResult,
    CognitoUserSession,
  } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

  import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

and then was using it in my functions

```
          const userPool = this._getUserPoolData();

          const user = new CognitoUser({ Username: usrLoginDetails.username, Pool: userPool });
          const authenticationData = { Username: usrLoginDetails.username, Password: usrLoginDetails.password };
          const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);



            user.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
              onSuccess: result => {
               //success here 
              },
              onFailure: error => {}, //error here,
              newPasswordRequired: () => {},  // no-op
              mfaRequired: () => {},  // no-op
              customChallenge: () => {} // no-op
            });
```

I tested it and got it running without any problems. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: error  ISignUpResult not found in 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'  import/named - after yarn add amazon-cognito-identity-js

Comment: @Wonderman This is quite old answer - you might wanna check the AWS Amplify https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js